# How can I get a green TeamCity build with muted red pytest run from tox?

Tags: pytest, teamcity, tox

I have the following `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py310, flake8
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
skip_install = True
deps = -rtest_requirements.txt
passenv = *

commands =
    pytest {posargs} --teamcity

[testenv:flake8]
deps = flake8
skip_install = True
commands = flake8 tests/
```

On teamcity, I run my python test through `tox` from within a script build step where I call the following shell script

```bash
#! /bin/sh

python -m tox .
```

Now, there is one red test that I want to mute. When I mute it, however, teamcity makes my build red even though it marked my test as muted, like so:

[image: teamcity error]

The problem is well-known, since 11 years, as reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-16784).

How can I modify my command in my `tox.ini` file to make my build green again? I don't want to mark my python test with the `skip` tag. I don't want to change the tox command from

```
commands =
    pytest {posargs} --teamcity
```

to

```
commands =
   - pytest {posargs} --teamcity
```

because that will just ignore any error that might happen during the pytest run (like "Internal error happened while executing tests", or "No tests were collected" for example).

Ideally, I would like to call

```
commands =
   pytest {posargs} --teamcity || [ $? = 1 ]
```

but apparently `tox` does not understand the symbol `||`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a custom shell script in your `commands` section, and there you can do whatever you want, including using `||`.

e.g.

```
commands = my_custom_script.sh
```

Comment: you mean ```commands = my_custom_script.sh {posargs}```?

Comment: I think you get the idea 